# Unable to access NodeJs server from tizen emulator

Tags: node.js, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am running a server on localhost:8080 and when I run the client on the browser it is able to connect. But when I run this on the tizen wearable(2.3.1) emulator it does not connect.

I have tried using my mac's local ip and even 10.0.2.16. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you add below privilege and policy in your config.xml as  it's required.

    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add below privilege and policy in your **config.xml** as it's required. 
`<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`

By adding privilege, it allows the application to access the Internet.
This privilege is for both native and Web application.

By `<access>` element in **config.xml** Developers can specify protocols, domains, and sub-domains.

Comment: can you please tell me is it possible to install nodejs server on Samsung Tizen Tv 5.0?
i explored several articles but no guide or tutorial i found.